# Opening other Python 3 files using tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter

I am currently working on making a program using tkinter that when pressing a button it opens the Python program, however I am having some problems with it. I have tried using `os.system('filename.py')`. That opens the file, but then crashes the GUI, making the user have to restart the GUI. I have also tried importing it as a module but that just does the same as when using `os.system`.

Can anyone possibly help me open a Python file in a completely new window/terminal?

Comment: What do you mean with "crashes the gui"? Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: The GUI would stop responding but the code to the program that was being opened would go in to the terminal that was running the GUI

Comment: The GUI stops responding because `os.system()` waits for the _command_ given to complete before returning which temporarily prevents `tkinter`'s `mainloop` from processing any GUI events. You should use `subprocess.Popen` to run another Python script concurrently with the GUI.

Comment: [How do you run your own code alongside Tkinter's event loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459083/how-do-you-run-your-own-code-alongside-tkinters-event-loop)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is filename.py will not be recognised by your os.
Instead of that use:

```
os.system('python filename.py')
```

This will successfully open your python file inside your GUI
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks that fixed the problem of it not responding, however the terminal would just open then close straight away.

Comment: That depends on the python file you are trying to run

Comment: They are both files that run using the terminal and are text based, no tkinter or anything else used